# A question regarding differentiating an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How does one differentiate the integral below to acquire $\dfrac{\partial^2F}{\partial a\,\partial b}$?
$$F(a,b) = \int_{-\infty}^b \int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \int_{-\infty}^b \int_{-\infty}^a f(x,y) \;\d x\;\d y = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x,b) \;\d x
$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial a\,\partial b} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{-\infty}^a f(x,b) \;\d x = f(a,b)
$$
**Warning:** This only holds if $f$ is sufficiently well-behaved near $a,b$.

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial a\partial b}$ by changing it to $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial a\,\partial b}.$

Comment: . . . . and then after that I went on to change it to $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial a\,\partial b}.$